# Using fmresultset form fmdb get Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs

Tags: ios, fmdb

I have two functions in the same controller using fmresultset. 
func1() works well but func2() keep showing Error calling sqlite3_step (21: out of memory) rs.
Please help!

```
NSString *selectIsbn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM cacheinfo where isbn= '9789576068164'"];
FMResultSet *resultSet = [db executeQuery:selectIsbn];
while ([resultSet next]) {
    NSString *resultsString = [resultSet stringForColumn:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [resultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
}
if (![resultSet next]) {
    NSLog(@"no object");
}
 [resultSet close];
```

Comment: Is that code your `func2()`?

Comment: Yes,just like my func1() but different executeQuery, so i can't see why func2() is not working. I call this in databaseQueue. Please help!